# STM32F4 : EEPROM 25LC256 management through SPI

Tags: stm32, spi, eeprom

I am trying to drive a [EEPROM Chip 25LC256](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21822G.pdf) with a STM32F469I-DISCO but can't achieve it. 
I have tried to make my own function with HAL API bases but apparently something is wrong : I don't know if I write datas on the chip since I can't read it. Let me explain more.

So my chip is a DIP 25LC256 (DS is above is you wish). PINs HOLD and WP of EEPROM are tied to VCC (3.3V). PIN CS is connected to PH6 (ARD_D10 on board) and is managed by the software. PIN SI and PIN SO are respectively connected to PB15 (ARD_D11) and PB14 (ARD_D12) with the right alternate function (GPIO_AF5_SPI2). PIN SCK is also connected to PD3 (ADR_D13).

Here is my SPI configuration code :

```
EEPROM_StatusTypeDef ConfigurationSPI2(SPI_HandleTypeDef *spi2Handle){

  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();

  GPIO_InitTypeDef  gpioInit;

  ////  SCK [PD3]
  gpioInit.Pin =    GPIO_PIN_3;
  gpioInit.Mode =   GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  gpioInit.Pull =   GPIO_PULLDOWN;
  gpioInit.Speed =  GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
  gpioInit.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI2;

  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &gpioInit);

  //// MOSI [PB15]
  gpioInit.Pin =    GPIO_PIN_15;
  gpioInit.Pull =   GPIO_PULLUP;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &gpioInit);

  //// MISO [PB14]
  gpioInit.Pin =    GPIO_PIN_14;
  gpioInit.Pull =   GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &gpioInit);

  //// CS [PH6]
  gpioInit.Pin =    GPIO_PIN_6;
  gpioInit.Mode =   GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  gpioInit.Speed =  GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOH, &gpioInit);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOH, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  //// SPI2

  __HAL_RCC_SPI2_CLK_ENABLE();

  spi2Handle->Instance = SPI2;

  spi2Handle->Init.Mode =               SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  spi2Handle->Init.Direction =          SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  spi2Handle->Init.DataSize =           SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  spi2Handle->Init.CLKPolarity =        SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  spi2Handle->Init.CLKPhase =           SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  spi2Handle->Init.NSS =                SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  spi2Handle->Init.BaudRatePrescaler =  SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_16;
  spi2Handle->Init.FirstBit =           SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  spi2Handle->Init.TIMode =             SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  spi2Handle->Init.CRCCalculation =     SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE ;
  spi2Handle->Init.CRCPolynomial =      7;

  if(HAL_SPI_Init(spi2Handle) != HAL_OK){
      return EEPROM_ERROR;
  }

  return EEPROM_OK;
}
```

And two functions allowing respectively (and theorically) to WRITE and READ into the the chip :

Write Function :

```
EEPROM_StatusTypeDef WriteEEPROM(SPI_HandleTypeDef *spi2Handle, uint8_t *txBuffer, uint16_t size, uint16_t addr){

    uint8_t addrLow = addr & 0xFF;
    uint8_t addrHigh = (addr >> 8);

    uint8_t wrenInstruction = WREN_EEPROM; // Value : 0x06

    uint8_t buffer[32] = {WRITE_EEPROM, addrHigh, addrLow}; //Value : 0x02

    for(uint i = 0 ; i < size ; i++){
        buffer[3+i] = txBuffer[i];
    }

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOH, GPIO_PIN_6, RESET);
    if(HAL_SPI_Transmit(spi2Handle, &wrenInstruction, 1, TIMEOUT_EEPROM) != HAL_OK){
        return EEPROM_ERROR;;
    }
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOH, GPIO_PIN_6, SET);

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOH, GPIO_PIN_6, RESET);
    if(HAL_SPI_Transmit(spi2Handle, buffer, (size + 3), TIMEOUT_EEPROM) != HAL_OK){
        return EEPROM_ERROR;
    }
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOH, GPIO_PIN_6, SET);

    return EEPROM_OK;
}
```

Read Function :

```
EEPROM_StatusTypeDef ReadEEPROM(SPI_HandleTypeDef *spi2Handle, uint8_t *rxBuffer, uint16_t size, uint16_t addr){

    uint8_t addrLow = addr & 0xFF;
    uint8_t addrHigh = (addr >> 8);
    uint8_t txBuffer[3] = {READ_EEPROM, addrHigh, addrLow};

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOH, GPIO_PIN_6, RESET);

    HAL_SPI_Transmit(spi2Handle, txBuffer, 3, TIMEOUT_EEPROM);

    HAL_SPI_Receive(spi2Handle, rxBuffer, size, TIMEOUT_EEPROM);    

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOH, GPIO_PIN_6, SET);

    return EEPROM_OK;
}
```

I know my function are not very "beautiful" but it was a first attempt. In my main, I have tried in the first place to write into the chip the data "0x05" at the 0x01 adress then to read this data back :

```
uint8_t bufferEEPROM[1] = {5};
uint8_t bufferEEPROM2[1] = {1};

WriteEEPROM(&spi2Handle, bufferEEPROM, 1, 0x01);
ReadEEPROM(&spi2Handle, bufferEEPROM2, 1, 0x01);
```

I have an oscilloscope so since it didn't work (monitoring with STM Studio) I visualized the CLK and SI PINs then CLK and SO PINs (can only see two channel at the same time) :

[image: Monitoring of CLK (Yellow) and SI (Blue)]

[image: Monitoring of CLK (Yellow) and SO (Blue)]

As you can see, with the first picture that shows CLK (yellow) and SI (or MOSI) in blue, I have all the data expected : The **WRite ENable** instruction then the **WRITE** instruction. Following the **ADDRESS**, then the **DATA**.

After that, the Read Function starts. First the **READ** instruction and the **ADDRESS** where I want to fetch the data. The last 8 bits are supposed to be the data stored at the address (0x01 in this case). Something happens on SI PIN but I guess this is because the HAL_SPI_Receive() function actually calls **HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive()** with my array **bufferEEPROM2** as parameter (that's why we can se 0b00000001). And so it is because of my SPI configuration parameter (Full-duplex).

Anyway, theorically I am supposed to see **0b00000101** on SO PIN but as you can see in the second picture.... nothing.

I have tried to change gpioInit.Pull for SO PIN on PULLUP and PULLDOWN but nothing changed. NOPULL is because that's the last thing I have tried.

The thing is I don't know where to start. My transmission seems to work (but is it actually ?). Is there anything wrong with my initialization ? Acutally my main question would be : why I don't receive any data from my EEPROM ?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write operations need some time to complete (your datasheet says 5 ms on page 4), during that time no operation other than read status is possible. Try polling the status register with the `RDSR (0x05)` opcode to find out when it becomes ready (bit 0). You could also check the status (bit 1) before and after issuing `WREN` to see if it was successful.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is now solved. Here are the improvements :

There was actually two issues. The first one and certainly the most important is, as **berendi** stated, a timing issue. In my WRITE function I didn't let the time for the EEPROM to complete its write cycle (5 ms on datasheet). I added the following code line at the end of all my WRITE functions :

```
HAL_Delay(10); //10 ms wait for the EEPROM to complete the write cycle
```

The *delay* value could be less I think if time is preicous (theorically 5ms). I didn't test below 10 ms though. An other thing. With the oscilloscope I also saw that my *Chip Select* used to went **HIGH** in the middle of my last clock edge. I could not say if this could also imply some issues since that's a thing I solved in the first place by adding a code line before `HAl_Delay(10)`. All my *SPI transmission* functions finishes this way now :

```
while(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(CLK_PORT, CLK_PIN) == GPIO_PIN_SET){
}
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CS_PORT, CS_PIN, GPIO_PIN_SET);
HAL_Delay(10);
```

This way I have the proper pattern and I can write in the EEPROM and read back what I wrote.

NB : A last thing that made me goes deeper into my misunderstanding of the events : since my write functions didn't work, I focused on STATUS REGISTER write and read function (in order to solve this step by step). The write function didn't work either and in fact it was because the `WREN`bit wasn't set. I though (wrong one) that the fact to write into the STATUS REGISTER didn't ask also to set `WREN` like the WRITE functions into the memory ask to. Actually, it is also necessary.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Some time ago I wrote lib for STM32 + SPI EEPROM. It was checked by STM tech support also. I am using this lib in about ten projects for now, it works good. Take a look [STM32-EEPROM-SPI](https://github.com/firebull/STM32-EEPROM-SPI)